# Heterogeneous combinations between two lists

Tags: python

What's a better way to generate unique **combinations** of pairs between two lists where pairs must also be heterogeneous (i.e. pair[0] != pair[1])? By combinations, I mean that I only want one copy of `(2, 1)` and `(1, 2)`. (is there a better way to express this?)

For example:

```
a = [1, 4]  
b = [1, 2, 3]  
magic_functions(a, b)
```

should return:

```
[(1, 2), (4, 2), (1, 3), (4, 1), (4, 3)]
```

I can get there using the following but it seems a bit cumbersome:

```py
prod = itertools.product(a, b)
pairs = set()
for x, y in prod:
    if x != y and (y, x) not in pairs:
        pairs.add((x, y))
```

Comment: In that specific implementation you don't need the `not in pairs` check. The the `set` will let add duplicate values and it will de-dupe them. No need to pay the lookup cost twice.

Comment: @aruisdante They are checking for (y, x) while inserting (x,y).

Comment: Why is there no `(2,1)`?

Comment: As @AshwiniChaudhary mentioned, I'm checking for the reverse to make sure that if I encounter e.g. (1, 0) I don't add it if (0, 1) is already there.

Comment: ah, ok, was unclear from the problem statement that `(1,0)` is considered the same as `(0,1)`, and not just a typo in your 'in' check.

Comment: Please be more specific in the question then. This constraint is "hidden" in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) instead of tuple, a frozenset is immmutable so can be stored in a set:

```
>>> for x, y in prod:
        if x != y:
           pairs.add(frozenset((x, y)))

>>> pairs
set([frozenset([1, 3]), frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([2, 3])])
```

You can easily extend this to store more than just pairs, for example if we had triads then checking for all of the unique combinations of it in the set will be cumbersome, but frozenset makes it easy:

```
>>> c = [7, 8, 9]
>>> prod = itertools.product(a, b, c)
>>> triplets = set()
>>> for p in prod:
...     f = frozenset(p)
...     if len(f) == 3:
...         triplets.add(f)
...         
>>> triplets
set([frozenset([1, 3, 7]), frozenset([1, 2, 9]), frozenset([8, 1, 2]), frozenset([2, 3, 7]), frozenset([8, 1, 3]), frozenset([1, 2, 7]), frozenset([9, 2, 3]), frozenset([8, 2, 3]), frozenset([1, 3, 9])])
```

Comment: Tuples of ints are perfectly valid to be added to `set`.

Comment: @aruisdante I know but OP wants to store only (1, 2) not (2, 1), so `frozenset`  will allow us to do that because we cannot use a normal set.

Comment: @aruisdante You're missing the point: `{1, 2} == {2, 1}` is True for sets, so instead of storing a tuple and checking for its reverse every time why not use a set. But as we cannot store a set inside of a set, I used a frozenset.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I misread the set-expansion (I had read it as a frozenset containing a tuple, rather than a forzenset containing 2 elements). Pointing out the immutability buries the lead of why this works, it's the fact that `set([1,2]) == set([2,1])`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) chain and combinations functions

```
import itertools
a = [1, 2]  
b = [1, 2, 3]  
q = set(itertools.chain(a,b))
w = list(itertools.combinations(q,2))
print w
```

which returns

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: This seems to be (too) clever (for me). Could you explain how and especially why this works?

Comment: Well the documentation explains how the chain and combinations works. But I first create a set of the two lists provided then the `combinations` function returns subsequences of elements from the input. Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each combination.

Comment: Read the doc for the methods for more, but essentially it's leveraging the fact that if you merge the two lists into a single list of unique numbers, then take the unique combinations formed from permutating that list with itself, you'll wind up with the output set.

Comment: Hah, I think I found a counterexample. With `a=[1,4]`, `b=[2,3]` you get `[...(1,4) ...]` as output, which is no element of the cartesian product (which OP seems to be looking for).

Comment: @Jasper you know what, you're right. I knew there was some information being lost here but I couldn't put my finger on it, and it's the restriction on parings coming from one element from one list to one element on the other, not just on unique pairings of numbers across both lists. The OP's example just happened to create a situation where that restriction was satisfied implicitly since one list was a subset of the other.

Comment: Hmm this answer looked really interesting. I've updated the example to include this case.

Comment: I did't see that on the question, but you are right. This solution would also  include (1,4)